# Phalcon relationships order

Tags: php, model, relationship, phalcon

Have such relationship in Phalcon, I need this query ordered by `log_time DESC`

```
      $this->hasMany('id', 'LogDevices', 'tk_fk', [ 'alias' => 'logs', 'order' => 'log_time DESC'  ]);
```

What right param I need to pass? Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Phalcon 2, it is supported:

```
$this->hasMany('id', 'LogDevices', 'tk_fk', [ 
    'alias' => 'logs', 
    'params' => [
        'order' => 'log_time DESC'  
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Have not found it in documentation) Thanks)